# Windows 10 has no Internet. RDP’d from Linux on same LAN. Which does DNS?

Tags: linux, networking, router, dns

My Linux machine was the boot server with DNS and installation images for my home LAN, but thought I disabled those services after my other computers lost internet access, randomly.

Now I RDP to my Windows 10 machine from Ubuntu 16.04 and have full LAN, but no Internet on the Windows 10 machine. Linux knows to use the Google DNS, but Windows 10 does not. I assumed my WRT1900AC router would handle this through the Verizon router, but it's not now.

**Topology:** FiOS MI424WR to WRT1900AC to Linux and Windows machine - hardwired

How do I fix the Windows 10 DNS issue? Less importantly, how do I make sure Linux doesn’t become a DNS server.

Comment: I did that before, but it restarted after some updates. I'll have to find out how it's restarting and tell it to stop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe is most likely not the DNS server, its much more likely you have issues with running more then 1 DHCP server on the network, and one is handing out an incorrect gateway.  Stopping the DNS server on the Linux box and reaquiring DHCP leases on the clients should fix the problem.